# If I use the Ankh and manage to kill the final boss, who gets credit for the kill?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

The Ankh item works this way: when you are killed it instantly teleports you to the previous room visited, turning you into [???](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/%3F%3F%3F).

If, while in this state, you manage to kill Satan/Isaac, who gets the credit for the kill, the character you choose or the Blue Baby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Blue Baby ( a.k.a. blue baby ) gets the kill.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I believe you get the achievements as blue baby which is a convenient way to get the d6.
If you're trying to unlock the d6, always play with Judas because he gets 5 soul hearts when revived.